# How do you pass a variable using stored procedures and dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, dapper

I am trying to pass an int to a stored procedure variable, but it keeps telling me Dapper Dynamic Parameters cannot convert to int. I seem to be doing it the same as everyone in the google guides and the Dapper guides I have found. Is there something I am missing?

Model Service

```
public async void CalculateAVG(UptimeModel response)
{
    var p = new DynamicParameters();
    p.AddDynamicParams(response.Websiteid);
    
    var websites = await _db.GetUptimeAvg(p);

    _logger.LogInformation($"Average is {websites}");
}
```

Data Service

```
public async Task<WebsiteModel?> GetUptimeAvg(int Websiteid)
{
    var results = await _db.LoadData<WebsiteModel, dynamic>(
        storedProcedure: "dbo.spUptimes_GetAvg",  new {});
    return results.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Interface

```
Task<WebsiteModel> GetUptimeAvg(int Websiteid);
```

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUptimes_GetAvg]
    @websiteid int
AS
BEGIN
    SET ARITHABORT OFF
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

    DECLARE @uptime float
    DECLARE @downtime float
    DECLARE @uptimeavg float

    SET @websiteid = 1;
 
    SET @uptime = (SELECT COUNT(Status) AS Online  
                   FROM dbo.[Uptimes] 
                   WHERE Status = @websiteid)

    SET @downtime = (SELECT COUNT(Status) AS Offline 
                     FROM dbo.[Uptimes]
                     WHERE Status = @websiteid)

    SET @uptimeavg = (@uptime / (@uptime + @downtime) * 100)

    PRINT @uptimeavg
END
```

Comment: does this help you https://www.learndapper.com/stored-procedures?

Comment: No vivek, I have already found and reviewed the top 25 google results.

Answer (score 0):

In your model service you are passing `DynamicParameters` to method but in your data service you are expecting `int` ?!

Modify your data service to be like this :

```
 public async Task<WebsiteModel?> GetUptimeAvg(int Websiteid) {
     var p = new DynamicParameters();
     p.AddDynamicParams(response.Websiteid);
     var results = await _db.LoadData<WebsiteModel, dynamic>(
     storedProcedure: "dbo.spUptimes_GetAvg", p);
     return results.FirstOrDefault(); }
```

Cuz I don't see that you are passing any params to your stored procedure

Comment: No dice on this one. Still telling me I am not passing any parameters